# Retrieving field `conversions` from fb marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I am using fb marketing api to retrieve the insights.

**request format**

`v8.0/{account_id}/insights?level=ad&date_preset=last_30d&action_attribution_windows=['28d_click','28d_view']&fields=account_id,account_name,ad_id,ad_name,conversions,conversion_values,cost_per_conversion,cost_per_action_type,actions&breakdowns=age,gender`

here i am requesting `conversions` field but not getting it.
I have tried all the breakdown combinations listed in [fb marketing api breakdowns doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns/#actionsbreakdown)

I want to retrieve the `conversions` field from the API. Is there anything that i am missing ?

Appreciate all your feedbacks.
Thanks

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the data using same API call.
Turns out fb will return the conversions data only when there is any data to return.
what is counted as conversion - somebody subscribed after clicking on the ad, that will be counted as conversion. Viewing the post is not counted in conversions.
also api call should have the param `action_report_time=conversion` to retrieve the conversions(mixed/conversions both works here).